# What's the best way to test sending/receiving MMS messages with Android?

Tags: android, testing, mms

I'm writing an app that stores secret (encrypted+hidden using [steg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)) information in MMS messages. Obviously I need a way to test this, in particular, sending and receiving MMS messages. I have one Android phone, a Nexus One. I know that [MMS's cannot be sent between emulator instances](http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html), but other than using up loads of MMS credit, is there another way of testing out MMS sending/receiving without just spending loads of money?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twilio just announced MMS support, and their marketing page has a test box to receive an MMS, could be useful for testing:
http://www.twilio.com/mms

Comment: Seems to be only US and Canada

Answer (score 0):

There are some websites that claim you can send a free SMS/MMS messages, such as http://www.text4free.net/ (**have not tried it myself though**) and commercial SW: http://www.nowsms.com/ (**this one works for sure but is not free**). Also there is a chance your mobile carrier allows sending messages via its website.